# Declare security constraint on user with multiple roles inclusive

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, roles, security-constraint

I have 2 roles.

One is `admin` role that can see all pages.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Other is `it` role that can see IT pages.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>IT Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/it/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>it</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Here I have a page that `admin` and `it` must access, but only in case the user have *both* roles `admin` and `it` and not only one of them.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin and it Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/other/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>it</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But the actual behavior of previous `<security-constraint>` is that `admin` **or** `it` role can access this page.

How can I achieve to apply that user must be declared to the 2 roles `admin` **and** `it` in order to access this page and not only one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Roles doesn't work that way. You seem to have the meaning of roles backwards. It's perhaps easier to think of roles as permissions.

Just create a new role.

Comment: I know that its just creating a new role but i am trying to see if this thing can be applied in web.xml